# Binding to a dictionary - with a key of ' ( '

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have data templates that looks like:

```
<DataTemplate>
 <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Fields[ABC]}" Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate>
 <TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Fields[)]}" Text="{Binding}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

For a class that looks like

```
class Source {
  public Dictionary<string, string> Fields { get; private set; }
}
```

When applying the second template, with the ')' key in the DataContext binding, I get a XamlParseException.  Is there any way to allow Dictionary Binding to work with other strings such as ')' ?  Some sort of escape character sequence?

Comment: I would try a straight pass thru converter and see if that does not somehow bypass this parse exception.  Or convert with a Linq strOut = dl.FirstOrDefault(kvp => kvp.Key == "(").Value;   In know ugly but if it works better than nothing.

Comment: try: `<TextBlock DataContext="{Binding Fields[')']}" Text="{Binding}"/>`

Comment: @jberger: That won't work as it throws this error: `Error 1 Names and Values in a MarkupExtension cannot contain quotes. The MarkupExtension arguments ' Fields[')']}' are not valid.`

Comment: i had seen something similar used in a recent answer, so worth a shot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could construct a valid path by using [path parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.propertypath.pathparameters.aspx), this makes sure the parenthesis is passed as a string and not part of the path description. The easiest way to do that would probably be via a custom markup extension as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9371469/xaml-markup-binding-to-dictionary-with-key-of-type-type/9371493#9371493) of mine.

The binding then could be written as:

```xml
{Binding Path={me:PathConstructor Fields[(0)],')'}}
```

*(Quotes around the parenthesis are optional but make it more readable i think)*

Comment: Thanks, this helped point me in the right direction.  I guess the real issue in the end was that some of the dictionary elements had leading/trailing spaces in them.  This PathConstructor format helps resolve this.